# What are the difference between global object and head global object?

Tags: javascript

What are the differences between global object and **head** global object?

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different things. The global object is [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

[There is no standard global `head`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#Properties) I *think* the `head` you're referring to is [`document.head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head), which corresponds to the `<head>` HTML element.

<sub>*N.B this answer assumes a browser, and not [node](/questions/tagged/node).*</sub>

Comment: ***The global object is window.*** not completely true

Comment: *document.head* is a JavaScript™ feature that is not necessary supported by other browsers (and isn't by IE 8 at least). The related [DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors) includes it as non–normative.

Comment: **window is the Global object’s delegate.**

Comment: @Pilot—the *window* object was a bit of a mess, hopefully it's getting better. There was a time in IE that it could be shown that the gloabl object wasn't the *window* object, but only in certain situations. And of course there are non–browser hosts that don't have *window*.

Comment: Yup my Sir @RobG..web browsers
implement it such that the window is the Global object’s delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Global Object

> The native objects are sometimes referred to as "global objects" since they are the objects that JavaScript has made natively available for 
>   use. For eg. Number(), String(), Boolean(), Object(), Array(), Function() are Global Objects

Head Global Object

> The "head" global object that is the topmost level of the scope chain, for example, the 
>   window object in all web browsers. For eg. Math, Window are Head global Objects.

The head global objects are derived to javascript from other languages.

[see more about this](http://books.google.com.np/books?id=QedCPXDfzjAC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=head+global+object+in+javascript&source=bl&ots=i_1hvW38Yy&sig=alPklOJ7teRUSPJAAk_43v8lKt0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jejpUsjnJYHqrQeEwoGoAg&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=head%20global%20object%20in%20javascript&f=false)

Comment: What are you quoting?